# Compare key values only once in 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

How can I compare values in arrays:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['2', '1', '4', '1']
```

just like:

`if (1 > 2) return counter++`,

first with first, second with second, third with third. If i do for loops i will do it many more times:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (Number(arr1[i]) > Number(arr2[j])) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

i just want to compare them only once, each key value with each key value. So in this example, counter should be 2

Comment: You don’t need a `j`. You just need the `i` and use it as index for both arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use 1 for loop like below. Since the arrays have the same length, you can just use the index from the first loop for both.

```js
var arr1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var arr2 = ['2', '1', '4', '1'];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (arr1[i] > arr2[i]) {
    console.log(arr1[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to compare the element of the first array with the second one.

1. Use 0 as a initial value of the accumulator/counter.
2. Check if the element of the first array passed in as the second
   argument of the reduce callback is greater than the corresponding
   element of the second array.
3. If the the above is true increment the accumulator.

```js
const arr1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
const arr2 = ['2', '1', '4', '1'];

const count = arr1.reduce((accumulator, element, idx) => {
  return +arr2[idx] > +element? accumulator + 1 : accumulator;
}, 0);
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a single loop and compare the values at the same index.

```js
var array1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    array2 = ['2', '1', '4', '1'],
    i,
    counter = 0;

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (+array1[i] > +array2[i]) {
        counter++;
    }
}

console.log(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested loop for that. You can do that using only single loop.
However a cleaner way is using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and getting its `length`.

```js
let arr1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
let arr2 = ['2', '1', '4', '1']

let count = arr1.filter((a,i) => +a > +arr2[i]).length;
console.log(count)
```